# doParallel "foreach" inconsistently inherits objects from parent environment: "Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function..."

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I have a problem with foreach that I just can't figure out. The following code fails on two Windows computers I've tried, but succeeds on three Linux computers, all running the same versions of R and doParallel:

```
library("doParallel")
registerDoParallel(cl=2,cores=2)

f <- function(){return(10)}
g <- function(){
    r = foreach(x = 1:4) %dopar% {
        return(x + f())
    }
    return(r)
}
g()
```

On these two Windows computers, the following error is returned:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "f""
```

However, this works just fine on the Linux computers, and also works just fine with %do% instead of %dopar%, and works fine for a regular for loop.

The same is true with variables, e.g. setting `i <- 10` and replacing `return(x + f())` with `return(x + i)`

For others with the same problem, two workarounds are:

1) explicitly import the needed functions and variables with .export:

```
r = foreach(x=1:4, .export="f") %dopar%
```

2) import all global objects:

```
r = foreach(x=1:4, .export=ls(.GlobalEnv)) %dopar%
```

The problem with these workarounds is that they aren't the most stable for a big, actively developing package. In any case, foreach is supposed to behave like for.

Any ideas of what's causing this and if there's a fix?

---

Version info of the computer that the function works on:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

other attached packages:
[1] doParallel_1.0.10 iterators_1.0.8   foreach_1.4.3
```

The computer the function doesn't work on:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

other attached packages:
[1] doParallel_1.0.10 iterators_1.0.8   foreach_1.4.3
```

Comment: Where is the `f()` function in your example code? Based on what you've provided, it seems as though the Windows machine is giving the right error as `f` is not a function, but instead a number.

Comment: From doParallel vignette: "To use multicore-like functionality, we would specify the number of cores to use instead (but
note that on Windows, attempting to use more than one core with parallel results in an error)"  I.e: windows does not implement something like `fork` used by doParallel, the workaround is to start an entire new R session to put the job in, IIRC it copy the parent environment, here the `g` function env and not Global one.

Comment: @brittenb Sorry, I made an incomplete change; I meant to do f = function(){return(10)}. Editing the original.

Comment: @Tensibai Interesting. That's for "multicore"-like functionality, but the package automatically uses "snow"-like functionality on Windows. Still, this may be getting to it....

Comment: No, unfortunately not. You can use "snow"-like functionality on Linux by registering with registerDoParallel(cl=2), but this still works on Linux and still fails on Windows.

Comment: @sssheridan "but the package automatically uses "snow"" <- as soon as you set the cores= to something above 1 it switch to multi-core according to the doc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Tensibai is right. When trying to use `doParallel` on Windows, you have to "export" the functions that you want to use that are not in the current scope. In my experience, the way I've made this work is with the following (redacted) example.

```
format_number <- function(data) {
  # do stuff that requires stringr
}

format_date_time <- function(data) {
  # do stuff that requires stringr
}

add_direction_data <- function(data) {
  # do stuff that requires dplyr
}

parse_data <- function(data) {
  voice_start <- # vector of values
  voice_end <- # vector of values
  target_phone_numbers <- # vector of values
  parse_voice_block <- function(block_start, block_end, number) {
    # do stuff
  }

  number_of_cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
  clusters <- parallel::makeCluster(number_of_cores)
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(clusters)
  data_list <- foreach(i = 1:length(voice_start), .combine=list,
                       .multicombine=TRUE, 
                       .export = c("format_number", "format_date_time", "add_direction_data"), 
                       .packages = c("dplyr", "stringr")) %dopar% 
                       parse_voice_block(voice_start[i], voice_end[i], target_phone_numbers[i])
  doParallel::stopCluster(clusters)
  output <- plyr::rbind.fill(data_list)
}
```

Since the first three functions aren't included in my current environment, `doParallel` would ignore them when firing up the new instances of R, but it would know where to find `parse_voice_block` since it's within the current scope. In addition, you need to specify what packages should be loaded in each new instance of R. As Tensibai stated, this is because you're not running forking the process, but instead firing up multiple instances of R and running commands simultaneously.

Comment: You should use `stopCluster(clusters)` rather than `stopImplicitCluster()` since you're explicitly calling `makeCluster`. Also, using `.combine=list` is going to give you lists inside of lists if you have more than 100 tasks.

Comment: @SteveWeston Literally 6 days after you tell me this, I'm running a code with `doParallel` and trying to `plyr::rbind.fill(data_list)` at the end and it's failing. I can't figure out why for about an hour and then I finally realize it's because of this comment. So thanks again for the heads up.

Comment: You can also export the variables after you make your cluster using `clusterExport(cl, c("list","of","variables"))`. If it's in a function remember to set `envir = environment()` because it `clusterExport` default is `globalenv`

Answer (score 7):

It's rather unfortunate that when you register `doParallel` using:

```
registerDoParallel(2)
```

then `doParallel` uses `mclapply` on Linux and Mac OS X, but `clusterApplyLB` with an implicitly created cluster object on Windows. This often causes code to work on Linux but fail on Windows because the workers are clones of the master when using `mclapply` due to `fork`. For that reason, I usually test my code using:

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

to make sure I'm loading all necessary packages and exporting all necessary functions and variables, and then switch back to `registerDoParallel(2)` to get the benefit of `mclapply` on platforms that support it.

Note that the `.packages` and `.export` options are ignored when `doParallel` uses `mclapply`, but I recommend always using them for portability.

---

The auto-export feature of foreach doesn't work quite as smoothly when using it inside a function because foreach is rather conservative about what to auto-export. It seems pretty safe to auto-export variables and functions that are defined in the current environment, but outside of that seems risky to me because of the complexity of R's scoping rules.

I tend to agree with your comment that your two work-arounds aren't very stable for an actively developed package, but if `f` and `g` are defined in package `foo`, then you should use the foreach `.package` option to load the package `foo` on the workers:

```
g <- function(){
    r = foreach(x = 1:4, .packages='foo') %dopar% {
        return(x + f())
    }
    return(r)
}
```

Then `f` will be in the scope of `g` even though it is neither implicitly or explicitly exported by foreach. However, this does require that `f` is an exported function of `foo` (as opposed to an internal function), since the code executed by the workers isn't defined in `foo`, so it can only access exported functions. (Sorry for using the term "export" in two different ways, but it's hard to avoid.)

I'm always interested to hear comments such as yours because I'm always wondering if the auto-export rules should be tweaked. In this case, I'm thinking that if a foreach loop is executed by a function that is defined in a package, the cluster workers should auto-load that package without the need for the `.packages` option. I'll try to look into that and perhaps add this to the next release of `doParallel` and `doSNOW`.