# R, error 'could not find function' in foreach with timeOut

Tags: r, function, foreach, timeout

I'm tring to insert in a `foreach` a timeout control like this:

```
#Parallel function
runnable_X<-function(ID) {
  require(R.utils)
  Sys.sleep(ID)
  return(ID)
}

#foreach function with timeout
foreach_timeOut<-function() {
  tryCatch({
    require(R.utils)
    withTimeout({

      out_list<-foreach(ID=c(1:20),.options.multicore=list(preschedule=FALSE)) %dopar% runnable_X(ID)

    },
    timeout=5); ### Cumulative Timeout for entire process
  }, TimeoutException=function(ex) {
    return("Time Out!")
  })
} 


library(doParallel)
require(R.utils)

#Parallel registration
registerDoParallel()

#NUmber of cores
options(cores=5)

foreach_timeOut()
```

I have this error:

```
Error in runnable_X(ID) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function "runnable_X""
```

If I declare `runnable_X` function inside `foreach_timeout` this doesn't happen, but I can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use built in functions, you have to add them to the cluster:

```
N_CORES <- 5   
cl <- makeCluster(N_CORES, outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterEvalQ( cl, {

  runnable_X <- function() { stuff }

})
```

Comment: I use the cluster  created automatically by registerDoParallel, I don't use makeCluster

Comment: I see, although you would solve your problema by adding the line to create the cluster, and it wouldn't do any difference to the code

Comment: This is just a "toy code", for other reason I don't want create the cluster. If I have this function inside an ad hoc package, the function will be visible inside the foreach?

Comment: If this function is insight a package you should type: foreach(x,
  .packages = c("package_adhoc")) %dopar%

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @karen for the help (+1) in case we have a cluster, but I have found this solution more fitting to my situation.

```
#Parallel function
runnable_X<-function(ID) {
  require(R.utils)
  Sys.sleep(ID)
  return(ID)
}
```

I will add in foreach `export` command with my function

```
#foreach function with timeout
foreach_timeOut<-function() {
  tryCatch({
    require(R.utils)
    withTimeout({

      out_list<-foreach(ID=c(1:20),
                        .options.multicore=list(preschedule=FALSE),
                        .export = c("runnable_X")
                        ) %dopar% runnable_X(ID)

    },
    timeout=5); ### Cumulative Timeout for entire process
  }, TimeoutException=function(ex) {
    return("Time Out!")
  })
} 


library(doParallel)
require(R.utils)

#Parallel registration
registerDoParallel()

#NUmber of cores
options(cores=5)

foreach_timeOut()
[1] "Time Out!"
```

Other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653567/doparallel-foreach-inconsistently-inherits-objects-from-parent-environment-e/34657594#34657594) related.